# Best solution in Rails for a 'image selector'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, forms, simple-form, picker

I'm working on a project similar to a blog where posts have several associated images. I've been conflicted for a few days about the best way to do this, and I was wondering if there was a good, standard way of doing it or if anyone had any better ideas than mine so far.

One option I came up with is use a [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) f.association combined with the Bootstrap plugin, [Imagepicker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/), but this seems messy and doesn't have a good solution for adding new images except to create a separate form, link to it, save the current form in the session, and redirect back to the saved form after creating a new image.

The only other option I could think of was to simply render the association with partials, and include edit/delete links on the the partials with conditionals so they only show up when needed, but again this needs the same solution for creating new images, and it doesn't handle the case where a user has a collection of images and those images are linked to the posts via a habtm relationship very well.

So, any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, this is the solution I finally decided on:

I used a simple form f.association to pick the associated images, then moved everything else out into the image controller to build a sort of 'image manager' similar to what Wordpress has. I put the image manager in an ajax modal so it didn't lose the current form data, then upon submitting the ajax form, I used jquery to carefully update the pictures options on the first form.